# Why is cacheLoadOnlyStoreAdapter throwing NPE during load?

Tags: ignite

We switched from 2.4.0 to 2.7.0. What might cause this? I can't rule out a problem in our code but we are not in the stack.

> 22:39:36.270 [mgmt-#66] ERROR o.a.i.i.p.task.GridTaskWorker -  Failed
>   to obtain remote job result policy for result from
>   ComputeTask.result(..)  method (will fail the whole task):
>   GridJobResultImpl [job=C2 [c=LoadCacheJobV2 [keepBinary=false]],
>   sib=GridJobSiblingImpl
>   [sesId=6461c7cd961-d4d7605d-33c7-4941-84bc-f6eca074593f,
>   jobId=7461c7cd961-d4d7605d-33c7-4941-84bc-f6eca074593f,
>   nodeId=503c524c-c53a-4f98-aadd-4c95ac2b168b, isJobDone=false],
>   jobCtx=GridJobContextImpl
>   [jobId=7461c7cd961-d4d7605d-33c7-4941-84bc-f6eca074593f,
>   timeoutObj=null, attrs={}], node=TcpDiscoveryNode
>   [id=503c524c-c53a-4f98-aadd-4c95ac2b168b, addrs=[127.0.0.1,
>   172.17.0.2], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, /
>   172.17.0.2:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1554182314332, loc=false,
>   ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false], ex=class
>   o.a.i.IgniteException: null, hasRes=true, isCancelled=false,
>   isOccupied=true] org.apache.ignite.IgniteException:  Remote job threw
>   user exception (override or implement ComputeTask.result(..) method if
>   you would like to have automatic failover for this exception). 
>       at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeTaskAdapter.result(ComputeTaskAdapter.java:101)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$5.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1047)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$5.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1040)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6655)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.result(GridTaskWorker.java:1040)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:858)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.processJobExecuteResponse(GridTaskProcessor.java:1077)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$JobMessageListener.onMessage(GridTaskProcessor.java:1312)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1555)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1183)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1090)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: null 
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1858)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:566)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6623)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:560)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:489)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1123)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1921)
>       ... 7 common frames omitted 
>       Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: null 
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:980)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5525)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJobV2.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5569)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$TopologyVersionAwareJob.execute(GridCacheAdapter.java:6184)
>       at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeJobAdapter.call(ComputeJobAdapter.java:132)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1855)
>
> ... 14 common frames omitted 
>       Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: null 
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7244)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.sessionEnd0(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:943)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:549)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.localLoadCache(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:608)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.localLoadCache(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:217)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5520)
>
> ...18 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter$SessionData.access$900(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:964)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.sessionEnd0(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:937)
>
> ...22 common frames omitted 
>       22:39:36.293 [pool-3-thread-1] 
>       ERROR c.b.a.c.c.i.cache.CeresCacheManager - There was an issue in loading data for cache ceres-daily-2019-02-27. Issue: ()
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter$SessionData.access$900(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:964)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.sessionEnd0(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:937)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:549)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.localLoadCache(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:608)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.localLoadCache(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:217)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5520)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJobV2.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5569)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$TopologyVersionAwareJob.execute(GridCacheAdapter.java:6184)
>       at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeJobAdapter.call(ComputeJobAdapter.java:132)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1855)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:566)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6623)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:560)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:489)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1123)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1921)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1555)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1183)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126)
>       at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1090)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
public class XYZLoader
    extends CacheLoadOnlyStoreAdapter<XYZKey, byte[], XYZRecord>
    implements ComputeJob, Serializable {

    public XYZLoader(...) {

        reconfigureCacheLoadOnlyStoreAdapter(gridNodePhysicalThreadCount, externalParallelism);

    }

    private void reconfigureCacheLoadOnlyStoreAdapter(int gridNodePhysicalThreadCount, int externalParallelism) {
        int physicalThreadCount = ...

        this.setBatchSize(...);
        this.setBatchQueueSize(...);
        this.setThreadsCount(...);
    }

    int[] getLocalPartitions(Ignite ignite) {
        //...
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    protected Iterator<XYZRecord> inputIterator(@Nullable Object... args) throws CacheLoaderException {
        int[] parts = getLocalPartitions(ignite);
        IgniteCluster cluster = ignite.cluster();
        ClusterNode localNode = cluster.localNode();
        int partitionCount = ignite.affinity(dataloadDescriptor.cacheName).partitions();

        Iterator<XYZRecord> reader = new XYZReader(parts, ...);

        iteratorFinishedFlag = false;

        return new Iterator<XYZRecord>() {
            // wrap inner iterator reader here..
        };
    }

    protected IgniteBiTuple<XYZKey, byte[]> parse(XYZRecord rec, @Nullable Object... args) {
        // parsing foo...
        return record;
    }

    @IgniteInstanceResource
    public void setIgnite(Ignite ignite) {
        this.ignite = ignite;
    }

    @Override // ComputeJob
    public void cancel() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
    }

    @Override // ComputeJob
    public Object execute() throws IgniteException {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
    }

    @TaskSessionResource
    public void setTaskSession(ComputeTaskSession taskSes) {
        ComputeTaskSession ses = taskSes;
        logger.info(... ses);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share code of your Cache Store implementation?

Comment: I can only share a highly redacted version. But all interactions with super are shown.

I will edit and add now if it lets me.

Comment: ok I squished it and now it fits.. thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

My bet that you forgot to call super.method() somewhere in your CacheStore implementation, leading to partial initialization of underlying data structures. In loadCache() or loadFromStore() perhaps.

Comment: Hmm didn't think implementing those necessary to use CacheLoadOnlyStoreAdapter. Don't see anything to that effect in the javadoc.

Comment: will look at example of this class in examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store per another post

Comment: Example is ./examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/CacheLoadOnlyStoreExample.java. I don't see it doing anything I don't really.

Comment: Can you put together a small reproducer project, upload it somewhere?